# how to Improve execution time of importing data in python

Tags: python

Below code take 2.5 seconds to import a log file with 1 million lines of code.

Is there a better way to the code and also decrease the execution time ?

""" This code is used to read the log file into the memory  and convert into the data frame
    Once the log file is loaded ,every item in the IPQuery file checked if exist and result is print onto the console"""

```
#importing  python modules required for this script to perform operations
import pandas as pd
import time
import sys

#code to check the arguments passed    """
if len(sys.argv)!= 3:
    raise  ValueError(""" PLEASE PASS THE BOTH LOG FILE AND IPQUERY FILE AS INPUT TO SCRIPT
                      ex: python program.py log_file query_file """) 


# extracting file names from command line  """
log_file_name=sys.argv[1]
query_file_name = sys.argv[2]



start = time.time()#capturing time instance

#Reading the content from the log file into dataframe log_df  """
log_df = pd.read_csv(log_file_name," ",header=None ,names = ['DATE','TIME', 'IPADDR','URL','STATUS'],skip_blank_lines = True)

#Reading the content from the IPquery file into the data frame query_df """
query_df = pd.read_csv(query_file_name," ",header=None,skip_blank_lines=True )

#Cheking if the IP address exists in the log file"""
Ipfound = query_df.isin(log_df.IPADDR).astype(int)

#print all the results to the Query results onto the stdout"""
for items in Ipfound[0]:
    print items



print "Execution Time of this script is  %f" %(time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Start by putting your code in a function (it's tidier, and local variable lookup is faster). Then Use the profiler to figure out what is taking time (https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html). Finally, if you can't figure out how to improve your hot spots, come back and ask for help.

Comment: 1 million lines in 2.5s? I wouldn't expect it to get much faster.

Comment: I am sure there  is a some other way

Comment: any suggestion to improve this code further are welcome friends

Comment: i  have figured it out that  the   pandas read_csv is taking a  lot if time and also the printing the values to stdout is taking lot of time

Answer (score 0):

```
#importing  python modules required for this script to perform operations

import time
import sys



start = time.time()#capturing time instance


class IpQuery:
    """Below methods contain the functionality to read file paths ,import log and query data 
       and provide the result to the console """    
    def __init__(self):
        self.log_file_name= ""
        self.query_file_name = ""
        self.logset = {}
        self.IPlist= []

    def Inputfiles(self):
        """code to check the arguments passed  and throw an error  """
        if len(sys.argv)!= 3:
            raise  ValueError(""" PLEASE PASS THE BOTH LOG FILE AND IPQUERY FILE AS INPUT TO SCRIPT
                              ex: python program.py log_file query_file """) 
       # extracting file names from command line
        self.log_file_name=sys.argv[1]
        self.query_file_name = sys.argv[2]

    def read_logfile(self):
        #Reading the log data
        with open(self.log_file_name,'r') as f:

            self.logset = {line.split(' ')[2] for line in f if not line.isspace()}


    def read_Queryfile(self):
        #Reading the query file into the  dataframe"""
        with open(self.query_file_name,'r') as f:
            self.IPlist = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f if not line.isspace() ]


    def CheckIpAdress(self):
        #Ip address from query file ae checked against the log file """ 
        dummy= self.logset.intersection(set(self.IPlist))

        for element in self.IPlist:
            if element in dummy:
                print "1"
            else :
                print "0"
try: 
    #Create an instance of the IpQuery file
    msd=IpQuery()
    #Extracting the input file information 
    msd.Inputfiles()
    #Importing the Ip information from the log files
    msd.read_logfile()
    #Importing the Ipquery information from the query file
    msd.read_Queryfile()
    #Searching for the Ip in log file
    msd.CheckIpAdress()
except IOError:
   print "Error: can\'t find file or read data"
except ValueError :
   print "PLEASE PASS THE BOTH LOG FILE AND IPQUERY FILE AS INPUT TO SCRIPT "
```